# Accessing Pandas DataFrame Objects from a list of DataFrames

Tags: pandas, python-3.3

I apologize if this question has been answered elsewhere. I havn't been able to find an answer yet through the search here or in the Pandas documentation (quite possible I've just missed it though).

I'm trying to import a html file into python through pandas and am unsure how to obtain the data I need from the result. I'm working on Windows 7 and using Python 3.3 along with Pandas

Using the read_html function in pandas appears to work and returns a list of dataframes. I'm new to Python (migrating from Matlab) and am unsure how to use a list of dataframes. The documentation describes how to use and manipulate dataframes, but how do I get a dataframe from a list of them?

Some of the other answers on this site suggest using the lxml functions directly to parse html files, however it seems the read_html is working fine in my case.

Here is the code I entered:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'F:\\Documents\\Python\\EA Performance Manager\\History.html'
History = pd.read_html(file, header=0, infer_types=False)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> History
[<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 428 entries, 1 to 428
Data columns (total 13 columns): 
Ticket         428  non-null values
Strategy       428  non-null values 
Symbol         428  non-null values
B/S            428  non-null values
Amount (k)     428  non-null values
Open Time      428  non-null values
Open Price     428  non-null values
Close Time     428  non-null values
Close Price    428  non-null values
High/Low       428  non-null values
Rollover       428  non-null values
Gross P/L      428  non-null values
Pips           428  non-null values
dtypes: object(13)]
```

I need to access the individual data columns for analysis (preferably storing them in array-like strutures - still learning to use python properly, will have to convert the data somehow as infer_type is false, but I think that is another issue). The question is how do I do this?

Note: The History.html file was downloaded from a web-based trading platform as History.xls, only after trying to use the excel reading functions to no avail did I find out it was actually a html file. The content of the file is the history of trade opens and closes for an automated trading system. The first row gives the heading for each column.

Comment: ``History[0]`` will give you the first element. FYI, generally uppercase names are used for classes; variable names are ``like_this``

Comment: The columns should be available by the notation History.<column name>. If <column name> is not  legal it will not work though. I would check the names and convert them. Then you can treat them like python arrays in terms of slicing and indexing, plus all the pandas subset goodness.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your help, History[0] gave back the dataframe allowing me to accesss the data using the History[0].<column name> as joel pointed out. Thank you also for pointing out the naming conventions for variables and classes, I'll start implementing those in my code as well.

Comment: @Jeff Is it possible to mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: @joel3000 I guess the column names not being legal would expain the nan results in the column names when infer_types=True? I had to edit names when using Matlab as well, however Matlab didn't automatically create column names from headers. I'm beginning to like Pandas.

Comment: so marked as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`History[0]` will give you the first element.

FYI, generally uppercase names are used for classes; variable names are `like_this`

These are just conventions; History is a legal identifier.

Answer (score 0):

For each dataframe column you wish to convert to a list, you can transpose the values, and then convert it to a list as follows.

Here is an arbitrary DataFrame with one column (if there is more than one column, then slice into columns, and do this for each column):

```
s=DataFrame({'column 1':random.sample(range(10),10)})
```

Then obtain the values using `.values` and transpose using `.T`, and convert to a list using `.tolist()`

```
s.values.T.tolist()
```

However, that might give you all of the values in long (with an L at the end of each).  If that's the case, then you can use a simple datatype conversion to obtain an integer or floating point, or whatever is desirable.  I hope that helps!  Let me know if not.